# Prevent 'beforeunload' event being fired on window.location

Tags: javascript

I have an analytics service which uses

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', endSession);
```

to record the user navigating away from the app.

In another part of the app we have downloading functionality, using

```
window.location = urlOfItemToDownload;
```

This causes the beforeunload event to trigger, which is undesirable.
There are many downloads in the app so toggling a boolean variable isnt so scalable. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Why are you using this event all the time? Maybe you should just bind it to the window only when there is an actual risk of data loss (Like if a form was not submitted for example)

Comment: Which event are you talking about? if you mean beforeunload, its basically a way for me to quickly send a message to the server saying that someone has closed the page.

Comment: Yup, that one - `beforeunload`, I only bind it to the window if the user started to fill in a form and didn't submit it before. I think that you can also trigger some internal flag for the download (Like `window.isDownloaind = true;`) and then return `null` based on that flag, inside the event callback

Comment: sure, but there's no other way of detecting the user is leaving the app, so I need it. And in terms of `window.isDownloaind = true;`, i mentioned why toggling a boolean variable is not scalable

Comment: Oh, I see. And unbinding the event and rebinding is also out of the question?

Comment: I think its the same as using a boolean, i might have to do that, it's just there's 40+ location in the app! thanks anyway

Comment: I think your problem here is using this `window.location = urlOfItemToDownload;` to trigger a download.

Comment: Yea, i cant get it downloading with anything else though i tried window.open() etc, any suggestions?

Comment: "*There are many downloads in the app*" - so make a `function initiateDownload(urlOfItemToDowload) { … }` and call that everywhere? Then - whatever solution you choose for downloading, and for preventing the event - it will scale.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm going to have to do - i initially wanted to avoid the labour of changing each line but I think it's the only way.